# How to update profile with current image when an image file is not chosen in the edit form? I am using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, crud, laravel-8

Whenever I try to only save profile changes for the profile description and url in the edit form, I get an error because I didn't choose an image file also.

I would like to be able to update a profile with current image when an image file is not chosen in the edit form.

The error I keep getting is:
Call to a member function store() on null

...that error is referring to this line in the update method of my UserController:

```
$imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
```

This is the entire update method in my UserController:

```
public function update(User $user, Request $request)
     {

       $data = request()->validate([
         'description' => 'nullable',
         'url' => 'nullable',
         'image' => 'nullable',
       ]);

       $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

       auth()->user()->profile()->update([
         'description' => $data['description'],
         'url' => $data['url'],
         'image' => $imagePath,
       ]);

    return redirect('/users/' . auth()->user()->id);

     }
```

Finally, this is the form in my edit-profile.blade.php file:

```
@section('content')
<body class="home_body">
  <div class="home_container_div">
      <div class="home_container">
          <div class="home_box_div">

            <form action="{{('/users/' . auth()->user()->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              @csrf
              @method('PATCH')

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="description" class="edit_description_label">Description</label>

                  <div class="edit_description_div">
                      <input id="description"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror"
                      name="description"
                      value="{{ old('description' ) ?? auth()->user()->profile->description }}"
                      autocomplete="description" autofocus>

                      @error('description')
                      <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="url" class="edit_title_label">URL</label>

                  <div class="edit_url_div">
                      <input id="url"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control @error('url') is-invalid @enderror"
                      name="url"
                      value="{{ old('url' ) ?? auth()->user()->profile->url }}"
                      autocomplete="url" autofocus>

                      @error('url')
                      <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="create_post_image_div">
                <label for="image" class="create_image_label">Profile Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                @error('image')
                <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
                @enderror

                <div class="create_post_btn_div">
                  <button class="create_post_btn">Save Profile</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
@endsection
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the image upload part if the user has not selected any image file, like this:

```php
public function update(User $user, Request $request)
{

    $data = request()->validate([
        'description' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required',
        'image' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    $updateData = [
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'url' => $data['url'],
    ];

    if (request('image')) {
        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
        $updateData['image'] = $imagePath;
    }

    auth()->user()->profile()->update($updateData);

    return redirect('/users/' . auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked perfectly!