# How to by default update a post with the current image when an image has not been chosen in edit form. I am using laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, file-upload, laravel-8

I would like to be able to update a post with the current image when an image file is not chosen in the edit form.

However, when I try to only save changes for a post caption or url in the edit form, I get an error because I didn't choose an image file also.

The error I keep getting is: Call to a member function store() on null

...that error is referring to this line in the update method of my PostsController:

```
$imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
```

This is the entire update method in my PostsController:

```
public function update(Post $post, Request $request)
  {
    $data = request()->validate([
      'caption' => 'required',
      'url' => 'required',
      'image' => ['nullable', 'image'],
    ]);

    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

    $post->update([
      'caption' => $data['caption'],
      'url' => $data['url'],
      'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);

    return redirect('/users/' . auth()->user()->id);

  }
```

Also, a Quick Note:
The image is required in the create method. However, I made it nullable in the update method.

How can I resolve this issue to allow for the current image to be used if no image file is chosen for post update?

Comment: If a new image is selected I would like the post to update with that image, hence the update. However, in the event that an image is not selected, then the current image should automatically be used, rather than hhaving to re-select it or get an error for not choosing an image.

Comment: You already asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593999/how-to-update-profile-with-current-image-when-an-image-file-is-not-chosen-in-the).

Comment: Just realizing that now. You're absolutely right.

Comment: I posted the code below, thanks for bringing that to my attention, @porloscerros. Only had to make one minor adjustment.

Comment: Great, I remembered seeing that question because I was about to answer it, but someone was faster. And while it's not for the same model, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check if there is an image file in the form..if so, you will upload and use that path name for the update, otherwise use the old image..

```
if ($request->hasFile('image') {
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
} else {
    $imagePath = $post->image;
}
```

and then put the code as you have now

```
$post->update([
    'caption' => $data['caption'],
    'url' => $data['url'],
    'image' => $imagePath,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I had already successfully tried the code that @porloscerros brought to my attention, I also tried your suggestion and it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function update(Post $post, Request $request)
  {
    $data = request()->validate([
      'caption' => 'required',
      'url' => 'required',
      'image' => ['nullable', 'image'],
    ]);

    $updateData = [
     'caption' => $data['caption'],
     'url' => $data['url'],
   ];

   if (request('image')) {
     $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
     $updateData['image'] = $imagePath;
   }
   
    $post->update($updateData);

    return redirect('/users/' . auth()->user()->id);

}
```

I did it like this and it worked @porloscerros Ψ . Thank you for bringing it to my attention. I only had to do one minor adjustment.